# Why are expanding/collapsing and scrolling ExpandableListView slow?

Tags: android, performance

I have an `ExpandableListView` which populates the fields of the rows as normal. However, one of the fields is an `ImageView` in which the path to the image is stored in a variable.  The problem is expanding/collapsing and scolling list view are slow. The expand/collapse takes around a second. Is this normal? Is there a way to make it faster? The code below is the `ImageView` code which I suspect it is the reason behind the performance (I commented it and the speed was acceptable)

Please let me know what can be done.

```
String imagePath = prop.getImagePath();
if (imagePath.length() > 0) {
    Uri mainImgeUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
    InputStream imageStream;
    try {
        imageStream = mActiviy.getContentResolver().openInputStream(mainImgeUri);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 8;
        Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        holder.mainImage.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please note that the variable prop was obtained from database which `imagePath` is stored as string in DB. The DB queries happened before even initializing the list so it does not have impact the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that this code block is inside the `getView()` method of your adapter, due to `holder.main...`. If so, this is a terrible practice because you should understand that this is going to be done to each one of the `ExpandableList` rows. The effects should be pronounced during the scrolling and expanding/collapsing because `getView()` would probably being called for all these rows and these images are being retrieved extraneously.

Much better is to set up a collection to hold these images and then bulk insert them once at once. Then you can use this image collection to populate your expandable List. Also consider using the `convertView` technique, if not already.

Comment: Ohhh I see . Yes I am using it in getView as you guessed. I like your collection method. So the conversion from path to bitmap is done externally and stored in collection but the holder.mainImage.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage) is still done in the getview, right?